# Setting up google assistant on windows PC

Tags: windows, google-assistant-sdk

I followed instructions in the below link to set up google assistant in my Windows PC.

https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/

But in the step while running the `hotword` command, i am getting the below `error` :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\310211247\appdata\local\continuum\miniconda3\lib\runpy.py",line 193, in 
_run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\310211247\appdata\local\continuum\miniconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\310211247\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\Scripts\googlesamples-assistant-hotword.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\users\310211247\appdata\local\continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\googlesamples\assistant\library\hotword.py", line 27, in <module> from google.assistant.library import Assistant
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.assistant.library'
```

How can i resolve this error?

Comment: This [link](https://github.com/shivasiddharth/Assistants-Pi/issues/49) may help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the [Compatibility section](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/overview#features) for the library, it is only supported on linux-armv7l and linux-x86_64 architectures. The library is not expected to work on a Windows device. Instead, you should look at using the [service API](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/).

Answer (score 0):

Google's recommendation is to use the assistant service:

> The Google Assistant Library for Python is deprecated as of June 28th, 2019

You can configure the assistant following these instructions:

https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/

After installation to get the hotword working you need to install the assistant library:

```
pip install google-assistant-library
```

Then you can run the google assistant with the hotword:

```
googlesamples-assistant-hotword --project-id project --device-model-id model
```